# Why I can not return a string type valuable in a toString Method?

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, tostring

I am trying to write a toString method for an object called ThreeDVector, which can print out a 3-d vector in terms of i, j and k, like “-2i+3.8k-j ” or "7i-5j". However, on line 96,  there is always an error says s1,s2, and s3 might not have been initialized. Since I have already initialized it, I guess there is something wrong with the variable type of these variables but I don't understand how to fix it.

```
class ThreeDVector
{
  double x;    // x-component of vector
  double y;    // y-component of vector
  private double z;  // z-component of vector
// For the purposes of this lab the z component must be between -1000 
// and 1000 (non-inclusive). 

  public ThreeDVector(){
    x=0; 
    y=0;
    z=0;
  }
  public ThreeDVector(double x, double y, double z)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    if (z>(-1000)&&z<(1000))
      this.z = z;
    else{
      throw new RuntimeException(); 
    }
  }

  public void setZvalue(double z) throws Exception
  {
    if( z>(-1000)&&z<1000 )
      this.z= z;
    else{
      throw new Exception("z value has to be in the range of -1000 to 1000, non-inclusve");
    }
  }


  public boolean isWholenum (double n){
    if(Math.round(n) == n)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
  }

  public String toString(){

    String s1, s2, s3;

    if(this.z>=1000||z<=(-1000)){
      return "undefied";
    }else{
      if (x!=0){
        if(isWholenum(x)==true){
          s1=String.valueOf(Math.round(x))+"i";
        }else{
          s1=String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", x))+"i";
        }
      }else if (x==0)
        s1=null;//if the coefficient is 0, do not print out that term 

      if (y>0){
        if(isWholenum(y)==true){
          s2="+"+String.valueOf(Math.round(y))+"j";
        }else{
          s2="+"+String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", y))+"j";
        }
      }
      else if (y==0)
        s2=null; 
      else if (y<0){
        if(isWholenum(y)==true){
          s2="-"+String.valueOf(Math.round(y))+"j";
        }else{
          s2="-"+String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", y))+"j";
        }
      } 
      if (z>0){
        if(isWholenum(z)==true){
          s3="+"+String.valueOf(Math.round(z))+"k";
        }else{
          s3="+"+String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", y))+"k";
        }
      }
      else if (z==0)
        s3=null; 
      else if (z<0){
        if(isWholenum(z)==true){
          s3="-"+String.valueOf(Math.round(z))+"k";
        }else{
          s3="-"+String.valueOf(String.format("%.3f", z))+"k";
        }
      } 


      return "("+ s1+s2+ s3+")"; 

    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Local variables must always be initialized. In your example, if the else part is never executed, then the Strings won't be initialized at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the variable types, but they shouldn't be null. Initialize s1, s2, and s3 to the empty string at the beginning of your `toString` method. Also instead of setting them to null, set them to the empty string where you don't get an appropriate value for x, y, or z.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
String s1, s2, s3;
```

use:

```
String s1 = "", s2 = "", s3 = "";
```

Also, I wouldn't use the conditional blocks where you set one of the strings to `null` since initializing them as an empty string makes this operation redundant. Put a `!` in front of each of their conditions and add them to the blocks that set the string to a different value.